# Pass Javascript Array containing multiple files to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to send Javascript array containing files to PHP using AJAX

The following are 3 files that I want to send to the php side. (These outputs come from `console.log(document.getElementById("id").files[0]`);

```
File { name: "img1.svg", lastModified: 1641853737982, webkitRelativePath: "", size: 2506, type: "image/svg+xml" }
File { name: "img2.svg", lastModified: 1641853677323, webkitRelativePath: "", size: 1060, type: "image/svg+xml" }
File { name: "img3.svg", lastModified: 1641853656789, webkitRelativePath: "", size: 1845, type: "image/svg+xml" }
```

In this case there are 3 files (There can be more or less than that).

The 3 files are in a variable `arrFiles`.
So console.log(arrFiles) outputs:
`Array [ File, File, File]`

JQuery file

```
var form_data = new FormData();
var arrFiles = JSON.stringify(arrFiles)
form_data.append("imgs", arrFiles);

$.ajax({
    url:url,
    method:"POST",
    data: form_data,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    success:function(data)
    {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

php file

```
if(isset($_POST["imgs"])){
    //Would like to handle each image separately.
    $imgs = json_decode($_POST['imgs']);


    //May be something like :
    foreach($_POST["imgs"] as $img){
        $movePath = "images/".$img['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($img["tmp_name"], $movePath);
    }
    return;
}
```

Is there a way to handle this ?

Comment: Yes that's completely normal and easy to handle. Uploaded files are always in `$_FILES` though in PHP, and certainly there's no JSON involved either, so that decoding makes no sense. If you upload multiple files, then `$_FILES` should contain multiple entries. You can debug with `var_dump($_FILES);` so you can see exactly what structure you're working with.

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with all that code?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to convert your file array to a string. It contains blobs or simply the raw contents of each files selected.
Just do this:

````
//New form data object
var form_data = new FormData();

//Since your files are stored in an array
//you just need a simple for...of loop
//to get each file item and include them in the formdata
//f will then hold each file item at every loop iteration
//(Notice the [] after imgs field name) was used for multiple file inclusion
for(let f of arrFiles) {
   form_data.append('imgs[]', f);
}


//You can do your stuff here
//In my app, I use window.fetch() Promise API
//Not ajax. Ajax is still cool tho
$.ajax({
    url:url,
    method:"POST",
    data: form_data,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    success:function(data)
    {
        alert(data);
    }
}); ```
````